# AngularJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined app.js:1(anonymous function):

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have moved my AngularJS test project into app.js, controllers.js and Services.js. After it my project is not running and not even a single page is being working properly.

i have attached my main source files here along with exception screenshot

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

        <!-- bootstrap App.js -->
        <script src="includes/assets/app.js"></script>

        <script src="includes/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <script src="includes/ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>


        <script src="js/CalculatorService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controller.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/assets/bootstrap.css" />
        <!-- demo.css is related to model window -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/assets/demo.css" />

        <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
        </head>

        <body ng-app="app">
        <div width="100%">
        <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" title="Navigation Bar">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularJS Tutorial</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="model-window">Model Window</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="simple-form">Simple Form</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="basic-form-validation">Basic Form validation</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="calculater">Calculator</a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>


        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="container" width="100%" style='padding-top: 50px'>

            <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
            <div ui-view></div>

        </div>
        </html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 
                         'ui.router', 
                         'ui.bootstrap',
                         'app.controllers',
                         'app.services'
                       ]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    console.log('in app config...');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                        url : '/home',
                        templateUrl : 'home.html'
                })

                .state('model-window', {
                        url : '/model-window',
                        templateUrl : 'model-window.html',
                        controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl'
                })

                .state('simple-form', {
                    url: '/simple-form',
                    templateUrl: 'simple-form.html',
                    controller: 'SimpleFormCtrl'
                })

                .state('basic-form-validation', {
                        url: '/basic-form-validation',
                        templateUrl: 'basic-form-validation.html',
                        controller: 'BasicFormValidationCtrl'
                })

                .state('calculater' , {
                    url: '/calculator',
                    templateUrl: 'calculator.html',
                    controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'

                });

}); // closes $app.config()

//let's define the scotch controller that we call up in the about state
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {

    console.log('in app controller...');
     // code for bootstrap angular-ui
    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

      $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            }
          }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
          $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
          $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
      };
    var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {


        };

        // Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
        // It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

          $scope.items = items;
          $scope.selected = {
            item: $scope.items[0]
          };

          $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
          };

          $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };
        };

});

// Start of a SimpleFormController
app.controller('SimpleFormCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      $scope.master = {};
    };

    $scope.reset();
  }]); // End of SimpleFormController

app.controller('BasicFormValidationCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.master = {};

        $scope.update = function(user) {
          $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
        };

        $scope.reset = function() {
          $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
        };

        $scope.isUnchanged = function(user) {
          return angular.equals(user, $scope.master);
        };

        $scope.reset();
}]);
```

**CalculatorService.js**

```
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app.services', []);

    console.log('in angular-tutorial-app Server...');


    app.service('MathService', function() {
        this.add = function(a, b) { return a + b };

        this.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b };

        this.multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b };

        this.divide = function(a, b) { return a / b };
    });

    app.service('CalculatorService', function(MathService){

        this.square = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a,a); };
        this.cube = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a, MathService.multiply(a,a)); };

    });
```

**Controller.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app.controllers', ['$scope', '$http', 'CalculatorService']);

app.controller('CalculatorCtrl', function($scope, $http, CalculatorService){

            console.log('in CalculatorCtrl...');
            doSquare = function($scope, CalculatorService) {
                $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
            }

            doCube = function($scope, CalculatorService) {
                $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
            }

        });
```

**Detail Exception when application runs on server:**

```
![screen shot of error and resultant page][1]
```

[image]

calculator.html

```
<div ng-controller="CalculatorCtrl">
        Enter a number:
        <input type="number" ng-model="number" />
        <button ng-click="doSquare()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
        <button ng-click="doCube()">X<sup>3</sup></button>

        <div>Answer: {{answer}}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have mixed the array notation for injected dependencies in your controller and in your module.

**Controller.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

app.controller('CalculatorCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'CalculatorService', function($scope, $http, CalculatorService){

   console.log('in CalculatorCtrl...');
    $scope.doSquare = function() {
     $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
   };

    $scope.doCube = function() {
     $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
   };

}]);
```

**UPDATE:** Remove `$scope` and `CalculatorService` in functions `doSquare` and `doCube`, they are already included as dependencies in your controller. Updated version above.

Comment: thanks, now app is being loaded, but still calculator thing is not working: i am looking into this why it's not calculating the values, but I am still getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined app.js:1(anonymous function)? is it normal thing???

Comment: How are you using doSquare() anyways?

Comment: yes, i have added calculator.html code above. have a look please

Comment: yes, {{answer}} in calculartor.html is not showing any results on the page. it's empty. i have checked, doSquare() and doCube() are not working on ng-click. can you please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app.controllers');

var CalculatorCtrl =function($scope, $http, CalculatorService){

            console.log('in CalculatorCtrl...');
            doSquare = function($scope, CalculatorService) {
                $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
            }

            doCube = function($scope, CalculatorService) {
                $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
            }

        };

CalculatorCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'CalculatorService']; //old technique to add dependencies

app.controller('CalculatorCtrl', CalculatorCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getList is not defined

**Note:** *In your case, the error says Angular is not defined, but for me, a function could not be find.*

that was because I forgot a simple thing, my code was like this:

```
 <a onclick="getList();"> Get List</a>
```

I called the Angular function by **`onclick`**, and it should be **`ng-click`**, in my case, I just needed to change that to this:

```
 <a ng-click="getList();"> Get List</a>
```