# Referenced Error: angular is not defined in app.js line 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

index.js

```
angular.module("travel")

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: '',
    password: ''
  };

  $scope.login = function() {
    AuthService.login($scope.user).then(function(msg) {
      $state.go('inside');
    }, function(errMsg) {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Login failed!',
        template: errMsg
      });
    });
  };
})

.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: '',
    password: ''
  };

  $scope.signup = function() {
    AuthService.register($scope.user).then(function(msg) {
      $state.go('outside.login');
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Register success!',
        template: msg
      });
    }, function(errMsg) {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Register failed!',
        template: errMsg
      });
    });
  };
})

.controller('InsideCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, API_ENDPOINT, $http, $state) {
  $scope.destroySession = function() {
    AuthService.logout();
  };

  $scope.getInfo = function() {
    $http.get(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/memberinfo').then(function(result) {
      $scope.memberinfo = result.data.msg;
    });
  };

  $scope.logout = function() {
    AuthService.logout();
    $state.go('outside.login');
  };
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
  $scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, function(event) {
    AuthService.logout();
    $state.go('outside.login');
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Session Lost!',
      template: 'Sorry, You have to login again.'
    });
  });
});
```

app.js

```
angular.module("travel" ,['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('outside', {
    url: '/outside',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/outside.html'
  })
```

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
            <script src="js/services.js"></script>
            <script src="js/constants.js"></script>       
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
            <title>FinalYearProject</title>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="travel" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </body>
    </html>
```

i'm getting angular js not defined error  by adding cdn of angular now i'm getting the error like 'travel' module is not found
Anugular js code is also updated as index js
Please help me in this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined app.js:1(anonymous function):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292970/angularjs-uncaught-referenceerror-angular-is-not-defined-app-js1anonymous-fu)

Comment: In which file u have written the angular code ?

Comment: Where is your ionic reference?

Comment: i've updated my code

Comment: @AsadArshad try the answer

Comment: i've tried but i still can't solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
// Some ionic reference
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <title>FinalYearProject</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="travel" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div ui-view>
            {{1+1}}
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('travel', ['ui.router','ionic']);
    //Configuration for Angular UI routing.
    app.config([
        '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('outside', {
                    url: '/outside',
                    template: '<h1>My Contacts</h1>'
                });
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/outside');
        }
    ]);
})();
```

Comment: The output will be "My Contacts".. which i set for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

The *angular js not defined error* might be caused because maybe the cdn couldn't be reached. So the angular variable is not created and this, when in your app.js the line `angular.module("travel" ,['ionic'])` is reached, **angular** is not found.

On the other hand your *"travel"* module is properly defined.

Comment: how i could reach angular?

Comment: Does the call to the cdn result in an error? Take a look at your devtool (on your web browser). If that's the case, you should try using a different cdn or just adding angular as a dependency to your project via *bower* or just by copying angular by hand on your project and setting the properly linking in your html to the new added resource.